# Parameter to find all records or exclude NULL

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have found several articles on how to accomplish the reverse of what I want to do with several methods (IS NULL, CASE, COALESCE), but I think at this point I am more confused than ever after reading all this and probably making solution harder than it needs to be. I am new to T-SQL and I am currently using VS 2005 to build a basic medical report.

I have the Date Range parameter working properly by using a convert command to ignore time stamp giving me all records for the day or date range. I am now wanting to filter SSRS reprot by perliminary report date to find records with preliminary report, or, all records in table.

- The database has NULL if no preliminary report was created
- The database has time stamp if preliminary report was created. (showing date and time it was created)

I need to find all records not NULL, or all records. (using a parameter)

I have a parameter "Display Prelim Reports only?" @PrelimOnly with a YES or NO answer.

If I use the following it will show all records correctly (all records not NULL showing only records with Prelim report/time stamp present)

```
LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date <> '@PrelimOnly' ----User selects YES it passes NULL
```

however, if user selects NO, how would I get it to display all records including NULL?

Thank you for any help

Thank you both for your help, it was ultimately a combination of both that got it going. Syntax is as follows.

```
WHERE (@PrelimOnly = 'NO') AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN @ReportStartDate AND @ReportEndDate) OR (LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date IS NOT NULL) AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN @ReportStartDate AND @ReportEndDate)
```

Comment: Just a tip regarding dates. Instead of removing time portions by converting to varchar(10), this is must faster. "SELECT DATEADD(dd, (DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.DateTimeColumn)), 0)  FROM Table t;" It calculates the number of days from year 0 to the date and add that value to the date 0. All datetime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of Iiya and Ian that got me the solution however the syntax was not complete and is as follows.

```
 WHERE (@PrelimOnly = 'NO') AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101)
BETWEEN @ReportStartDate AND @ReportEndDate) OR (LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date IS NOT NULL)
AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN @ReportStartDate AND
@ReportEndDate)
```

It requeired the Date and Time paramater to be repeated so that both paramters would still work, and the @PrelimOnly = 'NO' had to be first.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement in tsql to say if parameter is yes select records from table where conditions are true.

If no select records from table where conditions are true and date field is not null.

Answer (score 0):

here exist small trick:

```
((LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date <> '@PrelimOnly') OR (1=@AllowNull))
```

if user selected NO - set AllowNull argument to 1, other way set it to 0

NOTE: AllowNull - it is custom additional argument, you should add the same way as @PrelimOnly

another possible approach:

```
((LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date <> '@PrelimOnly') OR ('NO'='@PrelimOnly'))
```

for you full query you should do like this:

```
WHERE
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN ReportStartDate AND ReportEndDate) AND
(
    LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date is not null
    or
    ('@PrelimOnly' = 'NO') // if instead of NO VS sends empty string replace it here
)
```

Comment: In your first example, would user need to answer two questions? (I want to make sure that I understand the NOTE: Part)

In your second example, what is (''='@PrelimOnly') doing to the conditional statement? Is user answers NO and the parameter passes 1 for example, the conditional statement would say <> 1 OR ?

Comment: user should answer 1 question, the rest of logic is in your code. In second example - if PrelimOnly empty string - it will return all other way it will return all records where report date not equal prelim value

Comment: VS 2005 keeps changing it to this. Paramter sends NULL or Blank... Either way I get the same output, all results where LIS_Resuls.Prelim_Report_Date <> 'NULL'----------->WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN ReportStartDate AND ReportEndDate) AND (LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date NOT LIKE '@PrelimOnly') OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LIS_Results.Final_Report_Date, 101) BETWEEN ReportStartDate AND ReportEndDate) AND (' ' = '@PrelimOnly')

Answer (score 0):

Since `@PrelimOnly` can only be *YES* or *NO*, use:

```
SELECT
...
FROM
...
WHERE @PrelimOnly = 'NO' or LIS_Results.Prelim_Report_Date is not null
...
```

If the parameter is *NO*, the left hand condition of the `OR` is satisfied and all rows are returned, otherwise only those non-null rows will be returned, as required.

Comment: @PrelimOnly = 'NO' at the beginning was part of the solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! If an answer help solve your issue, please consider setting it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Will it let me set two answers to accepted? It was actually a combination of your response and IIya that got me to the answer I needed... and even then the syntax provided in both answers was not the complete solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But it's still entirely up to you which one to accept - I just left the comment since you mentioned it was helpful. But you can still accept none, too, if you think that's appropriate. This is fine - I won't feel bad and you shouldn't worry either. If you want to show appreciation to more than one, once you have a few more points you can come back and upvote as many answers as you like!